# Can't boot off of USB after installing FreeBSD

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, freebsd

So I recently installed FreeBSD on my desktop computer. It was very complicated, so I decided to switch to Debian. I tried to write Debian's `boot.img` file to a USB using the official Debian [help page](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en) but it still booted into FreeBSD.

Just to check, I used the USB on another computer, and it worked perfectly, booting into the Debian installer. I checked with GParted, and the boot flag was not set. I tried to set the boot flag using GParted, but it just showed a grey window, with no flags to be seen. I have a SATA hard drive on the FreeBSD computer, and an IDE hard drive on the other one (if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, instead of using GParted, I used fdisk to set the boot flag and everything worked perfectly. To respond to the person below me that said this wasn't an answer, I did my research. [These](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/) were the instructions I followed. The reason it worked was probably because I have an ancient computer that still cares about boot flags.

Comment: The OP answered their own question. I'd let it slide.